# I want to create a custom curved Listview which is scrollable horizontally in a curved style like a rainbow

Tags: flutter, listview

I want to create a custom ListView in flutter in a curved shape, which is horizontally scrollable in a curved style like a rainbow. The selected element of the list should be straight and the nearest elements should follow the rainbow model curve while scrolling horizontally

i want to create a listview in flutter like the image given above[please go through the required image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGsNm.png)

Comment: so it seems you need a `PageView`, not a `ListView`

Comment: here you have some code to start with: https://gist.github.com/pskink/c04de9b3d643b14051a6bca5189985c1, instead of `Transform.scale` you most likely need `Transform.rotate`